# GCC: internal compiler error

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

Вот ошибка которую мне выдал компилятор:

> internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
>
> int delete_struct(ProgramLang * structList, int num)
>
> Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if appropriate.
>   See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.

Я в первые сталкивуюсь с такого рода ошибками и не знаю что делать. Может кто-нибудь объяснить, что это за ошибка и как исправлять подобные ошибки?

Команда для компиляции, которую я использовал:

```
g++ -Wall -W -std=c++11 -o Kursach_2 main.cpp Database_functions.cpp ioStruct_functions.cpp ioFile_functions.cpp
```

Ссылка на github: https://github.com/JokerSamStrew/Kursach_2term
(код очень сырой и кривой)

Comment: Labzov  Как следует из сообщения, это ошибка компилятора. Возможно, она вызвана какими-нибудь витиеватыми конструкциями, используемыми в вашей программе. Поэтому сделайте рефакторинг модулей программы и компилируйте программу, постепенно ее расширяя.

Comment: Не думаю, что это ваша ошибка или  вашего кода. Ошибка памяти компилятора. Причин способствующих проявлению ошибке великое множество - ос, архитектура, патч уровень библиотек и т.д..

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Дело в том, что просто добавил пару функций, у меня main.cpp вообще ничего пока не используется

Comment: @0xdb А что вы имеете ввиду под ошибкой памяти компилятора?

Comment: @Semyon Labzov  Тогда проверьте эти функции и упростите их. Используйте простые и ясные конструкции.

Comment: @SemyonLabzov, попробуйте удалить файл `Database_functions.hpp.gch`. Думаю, это поможет.

Comment: @mymedia Вау, это каким-то образом сработалою. Видимо проблема была c github, спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это сообщение означает, что вы столкнулись с ошибкой в компиляторе. Такое бывает — ничего страшного.

Будет здорово, если вы поможете авторам исправить её. Для этого установите разрабатываемую версию компилятора (пакет **gcc-snapshot** в Debian / Ubuntu) и проверьте, воспроизводится ли эта ошибка снова (пакет ставит GCC в каталог `/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot`).

```
/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/bin/g++ -Wall -W -std=c++11 -o Kursach_2 main.cpp Database_functions.cpp ioStruct_functions.cpp ioFile_functions.cpp
```

Если ошибка не повторяется, обновите версию компилятора. В противном случае, пожалуйста, заполните отчёт об ошибке в [баг-трекере GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla). Обязательно укажите используемую версию компилятора (достаточно вывода `gcc -v`). Очень вероятно, здешние товарищи помогут вам, если с английским не очень.

Более подробную инструкию, как сообщить об ошибке, смотрите в файле `/usr/share/doc/gcc/README.Bugs`.

---

Исследовал вашу ситуацию. Поведение GCC подтверждаю. В последней сборке компилятора (от 2016-04-14) ошибка не воспроизводится.

В вашем случае компилятор падает из-за предкомпилированного заголовка `Database_functions.hpp.gch`. Иногда такое может быть, если он создавался с другими флагами нежели использующиеся при текущей компиляции. Для решения проблемы просто удалите этот файл.

*N.B.:* компилятор производит такой заголовок для ускорения компиляции, если в качестве входного файла передать .hpp